# Extending numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I'm new to Python/numpy.

I'm trying to extend numpy.array to give it some functions that make it nice for representing images (e.g. convert to greyscale etc).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from support import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Frame(np.array):
    def __init__(self):
        print "new frame"


f = Frame()
```

currently this gives me:

```
  File "o.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Frame(np.array):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances
```

I don't understand why this is an issue for Python?

Comment: Just as a side note you should check out: PIL Python Imaging Library http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/#pil117.
It has these abilities and converting to/from ndarray is quite simple

Comment: And if you are going to go with PIL, you should try its fork [`pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which is a more updated version that is also compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be subclassing `np.ndarray`, not `np.array`, but it's a little more complicated than just swapping on out for the other in your example. It's probably worth taking a look at the documentation:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html

Comment: Thanks for this. In the end, I classed 'around' it, rather than extend it, looks like the safer option.